# PHP Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in /Drupal Root DIR/modules/php/php.module(80)

Tags: php, drupal, pass-by-reference

Can any one provide the solution for the following error for Drupal website?

> Error - PHP Fatal error:  Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in /Drupal Root DIR/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code on line 1199

Comment: Instead of downvoting, please provide an edit or at least acomment why you are downvoting. It is not that bad question tbh ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the error is in `eval()` in the PHP module, the error is in your *content* which contains a PHP syntax error (as explained by yergo). The error is easily fixable if you can still edit your content.

If you are not able to edit the content, but can still access the module administration pagem disable the PHP module. If you can't, but have shell access to your server, you can use [Drush](http://www.drush.org/en/master/) `$drush pm-disable php`. If you don't have shell access, you can [disable the module manually in the DB](https://www.drupal.org/node/157632).

It is probably a good idea to stop using the PHP module, see [the issue that lead to its removal from Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/1203886) for the whys.

Answer (score 3):

> Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed

This error happens after PHP 5.4, where calling paremeters by reference in manner of:

```
myReferencedFunction(&$referencedParameter);
```

was removed from working. Methods and function have to be already declared to use parameters by reference like this:

```
function myReferencedFunction(&$parameter) {} // "&" goes here
myReferencedFunction($referencedParameter); // no "&"
```

So, if its a Drupal error, it smells like you have upgraded your PHP version from version lower than 5.4 to 5.4+. You have to downgrade PHP to version older than 5.4 or update your Drupal to compatible build.

**Edit:** btw, eval()'d code? php.module? Should you ensure that you dont have any rootkit installed.